# Cancelling upcoming phone call in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I making a phone call cancel app. Basically it cancel a upcoming call if your phone is in back position in table or ground (Accelerometer Data). I make a `Broadcast Receiver` and entry it on the manifest also gave action this `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent si=new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        context.startService(si);
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
            //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
            telephonyService.endCall();
            Log.e("in try catch", "yes");
            Log.e("in try catch", "call cancel");
            shrededit.putInt("newcallingstate", 0);
            shrededit.commit();
            context.stopService(si);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("pr", "out side true block");
    }
}
```

My code is running very well if i only use this code without the accelerometer service class but when i use accelerometer class and make a intent before this below code. My app not canceling the call or not giving any type or error. I think it but not completely sure it is context problem.
So please help me.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question i will take care of this next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,its not context problem all this code is perfectly fine you does just need a condition or use sharedpreferences for condition.
first make a sharedpreferences object in your service class or that which you show in intent. like this

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpref=this.getSharedPreferences("your_file_name",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sharededit=sharedpref.edit();
```

`sharededit.putBoolean("String_name", true);
                   sharededit.commit();`

Here boolean is not important you can choose and other data type it depends you.

Then in you `Broadcast receiver` class you have to again use these `SharedPreference` and `SharedPreference.Editor` function and you get the previous `boolean` value by this method

```
boolean value=sharededit.getBoolean("callingStop", true);
```

Than make a condition like this

```
if(value==true){TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(telephony);
        //telephonyService.silenceRinger();
        telephonyService.endCall();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } }
```

This is all now your code is run without any error.